# Getting Stock Price Data

Tags: python-3.5, stockquotes

Now that the Yahoo and Google API is down and it's not possible to retrive stock pricing data from those webistes, what other alternatives are there and how do I go about it?

This is the error I got:

```
raise ImmediateDeprecationError(DEP_ERROR_MSG.format('Yahoo Daily'))
pandas_datareader.exceptions.ImmediateDeprecationError: Yahoo Daily has been immediately deprecated due to large breaks in the API without the introduction of a stable replacement. Pull Requests to re-enable these data connectors are welcome.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Stack Overflow is suited for code / development questions. Discussions about product alternatives might find answers on other Stack Exchange sites https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub issue pretty much states what's up.

"Yahoo changed their API so that the old pandas 0.5 code did not work. If you would like to fix this, PRs are welcome."

There was a major break in the API used for pandas datareader, likely due to some API changes - they are accepting PRs on GitHub to fix this. There's an open issue here: [ImmediateDeprecationError:](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/487)